# CodeIgniter 3 - mysqli_init() error

Tags: codeigniter-3

I use VPS + cPanel from GoDaddy. Codeigniter 3 give error mysqli_init(). I updated Apache from WHM and installed mysqli. How to resolve this error?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ospVG.png

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to CodeIgniter 3.

Fix the extension_dir path in PHP ini property and this will work in both 2 & 3 versions of CodeIgniter.

Comment: post it as a comment or flag :)